# MongoDb C# failed to serialize the response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

Class (Entity)

```
public class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public Entity()
    {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
    }
}
```

Class (Member)

```
public class Member : Entity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Action

```
public dynamic Get()
{
    var response = UnitOfWork.MemberRepository.GetMembers();

    return response;
}
```

I'm building a API using .NET WebAPI and using mongodb as a datastore, I'm have some troubles serializing the responding object from the database.

Can't understand why, search the internet a while and found similar problems with no solutions. Either I'm a bad google searcher or there answer is hidden somewhere deep:)

Full stack trace: http://pastie.org/8389787

Comment: Why doesn't Get return IEnumerable<Member>? What's the exact exception?

Comment: It's correct that the Get method should return the type IEnumerable<Member> and this is what it should say, but the problem doesn't depend on the returned type. :)

Comment: Where is the error occurring?

Comment: So the exception is thrown inside the GetMembers method? If so, it would be nice to see the code inside the method :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is little guessing, but the code really isn't too telling.

I'm pretty sure this is because the C# Mongo driver's `BsonDocument` exposes a ton of properties like `AsBoolean`, `AsInt`, `AsString`, etc. Calling those getters on data that isn't convertible to the respective type causes an exception. While I don't see them in the stack trace, that might be a compiler optimization.

One solution is to make the code strongly-typed (if it isn't already). I don't know what `UnitOfWork.MemberRepository.GetMembers();` is, but it hides what you're doing and it's also not clear what it returns. You're losing a lot of the advantages of the C# driver. The `Collection<T>` class is pretty much a repository pattern already by the way.

A cleaner approach (they aren't mutually exclusive) is to not serialize the database object to the outside world, but use *DTO* for the WebAPI side and translate between them, for instance using AutoMapper. I would always do this, because you're throwing an object that might be decorated with DB-Attributes in a serializer you don't know - that could lead to all sorts of problems. Also, you often want to hide certain information from the outside, or make it read-only.

Another option is to use `ServiceStack.Text` as a JSON-serializer instead, which tends to cause less trouble in my experience.

Comment: Great ideas, I'm thinking about try you suggestion on a AutoMapper approach.